# GDI+ LinearGradientBrush bug

Tags: .net-3.5, gdi+

Thee years ago this question was asked here [LinearGradientBrush Artifact Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110081/lineargradientbrush-artifact-workaround)

We have some code was written at that time. We used workaround. Now we refactor our code.
Does this bug still exists in .Net 3.5?

Comment: It is floating point rounding problem.  You fix it by setting Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to PixelOffsetMode.Half;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is floating point rounding problem. You fix it by setting Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to PixelOffsetMode.Half; –  Hans Passant Dec 8 '11 at 13:32